# pthread conditional wait in c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm not sure how to ask this other than to give an example of what I'm trying to do, so here goes. Suppose I have threads A,B,C,D,E and F. I have a shared resource called *Car*. The *Car* is able to fit 2 people in it, aka threads. So now I'm going to create threads in chronological order from A->F. However, only 2 threads can use the *Car* at a time. So at time 1, we see that Threads A and B are using the *Car*. Suppose thread B is now getting off the *Car* and now we have an open spot. This spot is filled by thread C. And so on, until each thread has a turn in the *Car*. What is the best way to be able to accomplish this? All threads must be running, and only 2 can be using the shared resource at a time, in case I did not make that clear. I've thought about somehow implementing a thread queue. Such that when one gets done it can signal the next, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Thanks for any and all help.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't make clear that only the following letter can get in the *Car* next, so for example if B got out of the *Car* then only C is allowed to enter the *Car* next. If A gets out while the *Car* contains {A,C} then D should be notified to get in the *Car*, so now *Car* contains {D,C} and so and so forth until all threads has had a chance to ride in the *Car*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the mechanism you are looking for is a [semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html):

```
A semaphore is an integer whose value is never allowed to fall below
zero.  Two operations can be performed on semaphores: increment the
semaphore value by one (sem_post(3)); and decrement the semaphore
value by one (sem_wait(3)).  If the value of a semaphore is currently
zero, then a sem_wait(3) operation will block until the value becomes
greater than zero.
```

Set the semaphore's initial value to 2 (in your [sem_init()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) call), and have each thread call [sem_wait()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) before getting into the Car, and [sem_post()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html) after getting off the Car, and you should get the behavior you want.

Comment: sorry, I didn't make clear that I wanted the threads to get in the *Car* in a certain order. From A-F. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: You might get better results if you relax that requirement.  Multithreading and strict ordering requirements go together like oil and water.

Comment: It's for a school project and therefore I can't relax that requirement. I have to do what comes next in order. Although there are multiple cars if that helps haha. So I'll have pools of threads waiting on different cars etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a semaphore, or you could use a counter and a condition variable to get a similar effect.

In the examples below, `nthreads` is an integer to keep track of the number of threads in the *Car*, `mutex` is a `pthread_mutex_t` to protect `nthreads`, and `cond` is a `pthread_cond_t` for signalling waiting threads when another thread leaves the *Car*.

So to enter the *Car*, each thread would use:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while (nthreads >= 2)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  nthreads++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

And to leave the *Car*, a thread would use:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  nthreads--;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Note that the mutex protects `nthreads`, not the *Car*... it's `nthreads` that protects the *Car*.  Also note that the condition is signalled before unlocking the mutex to make sure it won't be missed, and that the condition wait is in a loop in case the wait is prematurely interrupted while the `nthreads` count is still too high.

Comment: I've made an update to the original post to reflect that I want each thread to get in the *Car* in order. So for example if the *Car* contains {A,B} and then one of them gets out, only C is allowed to enter the *Car*, not just any thread that wants in.